# LaTeX reference and Makefile

Tags: makefile, latex

I'm using `Makefile` to generate PDF from `.tex` files.

When references was used in my LaTeX files. sometimes I get something like

`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`

I know that re-run LaTeX compile command can fix this reference problem, but in my `Makefile`, `%.pdf` only depends on `%.tex`，thus just run `make` again doesn't fix the problem (nothing changed in `.tex` file). I need to do a `make clean` to re-generate PDF again.

Here's my `Makefile`

```
TEX := $(wildcard *.tex)
default: $(TEX:.tex=.pdf)
%.pdf: %.tex
    xelatex $<
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -v *.aux *.toc *.log *.out
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

UPDATE:

Here's some thought I found from Google

1. Change `default` target to be a `.PHONY`. Which is not a very good solution (because there's so may latex file there, and I just need to re-compile a single file)
2. Change `%.pdf`'s dependency to include `%.aux`. But I don't know if it's possible in GNU make? (depends on `%.aux` file if it exists, otherwise ignore the dependency on `%.aux`)
3. Do a `grep` to the `.log` file and find the specific warning. If it exists, re-run compile command.

Comment: You might benefit from looking at [latexmk](http://ctan.tug.org/pkg/latexmk), which is a part of most fine TeX distros.

Answer (score 12):

I use in all my LaTeX makefiles the simple rule

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

%.pdf %.aux %.idx: %.tex
        pdflatex $<
        while grep 'Rerun to get ' $*.log ; do pdflatex $< ; done
```

This repeats pdflatex as often as necessary. I found that all the different LaTeX messages that call for a rerun contain the common string "Rerun to get " in the log file, so you can just test for its presence with grep in a while loop.

The ".DELETE_ON_ERROR:" setting is important: it ensures that make automatically deletes any remaining incomplete pdf/aux/idx files whenever TeX aborts with an error, such that they cannot confuse make when you call it next time.

When I use DVI rather than PDF as the output format, I use equivalently

```
%.dvi %.aux %.idx: %.tex
        latex $<
        while grep 'Rerun to get ' $*.log ; do latex $< ; done
        -killall -USR1 -r xdvi || true
```

The last line causes any running xdvi to reload its input file, for instant visual inspection.

Comment: Great solution! I like adding `-interaction nonstopmode` to the first `pdflatex` so that it just quits on errors, and add `-interaction batchmode` to the command in the while loop so that you don't get tons of output when its just rerunning.

Answer (score 0):

Either make "default" a phony target (Add "default" to the line starting with .PHONY), or build a more complex dependency structure, which reruns automatically (can't say how to do that, sorry).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think making `default` a `.PHONY` is a good idea since there are many tex files there and I just need to re-compile a single `.tex` file.